# How do I return a new dictionary if the keys in one dictionary, match the keys in another dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

Currently, I have a dictionary, with its key representing a zip code, and the values are also a dictionary.

```
d = { 94111: {'a': 5,  'b': 7,  'd': 7}, 
      95413: {'a': 6,  'd': 4}, 
      84131: {'a': 5,  'b': 15, 'c': 10, 'd': 11}, 
      73173: {'a': 15, 'c': 10, 'd': 15}, 
      80132: {'b': 7,  'c': 7,  'd': 7} }
```

And then a second dictionary, which associates which state the zip code belongs to.

```
states = {94111: "TX", 84131: "TX", 95413: "AL", 73173: "AL", 80132: "AL"}
```

If the zip code in the dictionary `states` matches one of the keys in `db` then it would sum up those values and put it into a new dictionary like the expected output.

**Expected Output:**

```
{'TX': {'a': 10, 'b': 22, 'd': 18, 'c': 10}, 'AL': {'a': 21, 'd': 26, 'c': 17, 'b': 7}}
```

So far this is the direction I am looking to go into but I'm not sure when both the keys match, how to create a dictionary that will look like the expected output.

```
def zips(d, states):
    result = dict()
    for key, value in db.items():
        for keys, values in states.items():
            if key == keys:


zips(d, states)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using `collections` module

**Ex:**

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter

d = { 94111: {'a': 5,  'b': 7,  'd': 7}, 
      95413: {'a': 6,  'd': 4}, 
      84131: {'a': 5,  'b': 15, 'c': 10, 'd': 11}, 
      73173: {'a': 15, 'c': 10, 'd': 15}, 
      80132: {'b': 7,  'c': 7,  'd': 7} }

states = {94111: "TX", 84131: "TX", 95413: "AL", 73173: "AL", 80132: "AL"}

result = defaultdict(Counter)
for k,v in d.items():
    if k in states:
        result[states[k]] += Counter(v)
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
defaultdict(<class 'collections.Counter'>, {'AL': Counter({'d': 26, 'a': 21, 'c': 17, 'b': 7}), 
'TX': Counter({'b': 22, 'd': 18, 'a': 10, 'c': 10})})
```

Comment: I thought that using classes from collections was faster than bulit-in container but after testing it appears that your solution is slower, why ?

Comment: Hi @Rakesh, any specific reasons as to why you go with `defaultdict` rather than usual `dict`?

Comment: @SwadhikarC..https://www.accelebrate.com/blog/using-defaultdict-python/

Comment: @T.Lucas `Counter`, at least, is a pure-Python, user-defined subclass of `dict`. There's no reason it would be faster than a `dict` alone.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use defaultdict and count in a loop:

```
expected_output = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
for postcode, state in states.items():
     for key, value in d.get(postcode, {}).items():
         expected_output[state][key] += value
```

Comment: What about `defaultdict(Counter)`?

Answer (score 1):

Just as a complement of the answer of Rakesh, Here is an answer closer to your code:

```
res = {v:{} for v in states.values()}

for k,v in states.items():
    if k in d:
        sub_dict = d[k]
        output_dict = res[v]
        for sub_k,sub_v in sub_dict.items():
            output_dict[sub_k] = output_dict.get(sub_k, 0) + sub_v
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
d = { 94111: {'a': 5,  'b': 7,  'd': 7},                                                                                                                                                
      95413: {'a': 6,  'd': 4},                                                                 
      84131: {'a': 5,  'b': 15, 'c': 10, 'd': 11},                                              
      73173: {'a': 15, 'c': 10, 'd': 15},                                                       
      80132: {'b': 7,  'c': 7,  'd': 7} }                                                       
states = {94111: "TX", 84131: "TX", 95413: "AL", 73173: "AL", 80132: "AL"}                         

out = {i: 0 for i in states.values()}                                                              
for key, value in d.items():                                                                       
    if key in states:                                                                              
        if not out[states[key]]:                                                                   
            out[states[key]] = value                                                               
        else:                                                                                      
            for k, v in value.items():                                                             
                if k in out[states[key]]:                                                          
                    out[states[key]][k] += v                                                       
                else:                                                                              
                    out[states[key]][k] = v                                                        
# out -> {'TX': {'a': 10, 'b': 22, 'd': 18, 'c': 10}, 'AL': {'a': 21, 'd': 26, 'c': 17, 'b': 7}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the class `Counter` for counting objects:

```
from collections import Counter

d = { 94111: {'a': 5,  'b': 7,  'd': 7}, 
      95413: {'a': 6,  'd': 4}, 
      84131: {'a': 5,  'b': 15, 'c': 10, 'd': 11}, 
      73173: {'a': 15, 'c': 10, 'd': 15}, 
      80132: {'b': 7,  'c': 7,  'd': 7} }

states = {94111: "TX", 84131: "TX", 95413: "AL", 73173: "AL", 80132: "AL"}

new_d = {}
for k, v in d.items():
    if k in states:
        new_d.setdefault(states[k], Counter()).update(v)

print(new_d)
# {'TX': Counter({'b': 22, 'd': 18, 'a': 10, 'c': 10}), 'AL': Counter({'d': 26, 'a': 21, 'c': 17, 'b': 7})}
```

You can convert `new_d` to the dictionary of dictionaries:

```
for k, v in new_d.items():
    new_d[k] = dict(v)

print(new_d)
# {'TX': {'a': 10, 'b': 22, 'd': 18, 'c': 10}, 'AL': {'a': 21, 'd': 26, 'c': 17, 'b': 7}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage `dict`'s `.items()` method, which returns a list of tuples, and get the expected output in a simple one-liner:

`new_dict = {value:d[key] for key, value in states.items()}`

Output:

`{'AL': {'b': 7, 'c': 7, 'd': 7}, 'TX': {'a': 5, 'b': 15, 'c': 10, 'd': 11}}`

Answer (score 0):

You might want to reconsider your choice of `dict` for how to store your data. If you store your data using pandas, aggregation is a lot easier.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d).transpose()
df['states']=pd.Series(states)
df.groupby('states').sum()

>>            a     b     c     d
>>states                        
>>AL      21.0   7.0  17.0  26.0
>>TX      10.0  22.0  10.0  18.0
```